# Group Action and stabilizer problem.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, stabilizer

$n$ is a positive integer the group $S_n$ acts on the set $A={1,2,....,n}$ as :

$s\cdot i = s(i)$ for all $i \in $ {1,2,...,n}.

We need to show that the action is faithful and the stabilizer $G_i$ is isomorphic to $S_{n-1}$.

I tried the first part as follows :

If I somehow show that the Kernel $K$ of the group action only contains the identity element , this would imply the action is faithful.

So , $K = [ s \in S_n | s\cdot i = i]$ for all values of $i$.

=> $s(i)=i$ , which is the cycle that maps each element to itself only , which is an identity element for $S_n$ and hence group action is faithful.

Now for the second part , for stabilizer $G_i$ we know $i$ is fixed , but since $K= (1)$ thus $G_i = (1)$ , but how to show that it is isomorphic to $S_{n-1}$ ?
Could anyone help ?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $G_i:= \{s \in S \mid s \cdot i = i\}$, that is, $G_i$ consists of the permutations in $S_n$ that fix $i$. You can view such permutations as just permutations of the other $n-1$ elements of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel of the action $\phi$ is the intersection of all the pointwise stabilizers, namely:
\begin{alignat}{1}
\operatorname{ker}\phi &= \bigcap_{i\in A}\operatorname{Stab}(i) \\
&= \{\sigma\in S_n\mid \sigma(i)=i,\text{ for all }i\in A\} \\
&= \{1_{S_n}\}
\end{alignat}
and hence the action is faithful.

For the second part, consider more generally any set $X\subseteq A$, and for any $\sigma\in S_X$ its extension $\alpha_\sigma$ to $A$ by the indentity map of $A\setminus X$:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&\alpha_\sigma(i) :=\sigma(i),&&\text{ for }i\in X \\
&\alpha_\sigma(i):=i,&&\text{ for }i\in A\setminus X \\
\end{alignat}
Clearly, $\alpha_\sigma\in S_n$. Now, for $\sigma,\tau\in S_X$ and $i\in X$:
\begin{alignat}{1}
\alpha_{\sigma\tau}(i) &= (\sigma\tau)(i) \\
&= \sigma(\tau(i)) \\
&= \alpha_\sigma(\alpha_\tau(i)) \\
&= (\alpha_\sigma\alpha_\tau)(i) \\
\end{alignat}
and for $i\in A\setminus X$:
\begin{alignat}{1}
\alpha_{\sigma\tau}(i) &= i \\
&= \alpha_\sigma(\alpha_\tau(i)) \\
&= (\alpha_\sigma\alpha_\tau)(i) \\
\end{alignat}
whence:
\begin{alignat}{1}
\alpha_{\sigma\tau} &= \alpha_\sigma\alpha_\tau \\
\end{alignat}
Moreover, from $\alpha_\sigma=1_{S_n}$ follows $\sigma(i)=i$ for every $i\in X$, namely $\sigma=1_{S_X}$. So:
$$S_X\stackrel{\alpha}{\hookrightarrow} S_n$$
The claim follows by taking $X:=A\setminus\{i\}$ (whence $S_X\cong S_{n-1}$) and noting that $S_X\cong\alpha(S_X)=G_i$.